# Autohotkey: Get debugging window (floating mode) of PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, autohotkey, windows-7-x64

Woraround with Autohotkey (scripting language in Windows, here Win7).
How do I get debugging window (floating mode) of PhpStorm again?
Once I switch in the floating mode (PhpStorm version 9) is the window is No Longer visible and even non-existent (titles and class names are known to me from a load attempt with AutoHotkey). Now debugging Window Seems not exist (says Autohotkey).
Here is the code with which I've been trying to find the window:

```
 DetectHiddenWindows,On
 SetTitleMatchMode , 1
;~ if(WinExist("ahk_class" . ClassName)) ; 
w=SL5_preg_contentFinder ; woks with this
w=Debug
if(WinExist(w)) ; its case insensitive
{
    WinGetTitle , title, %w%
    WinGetClass,class,A
    MsgBox,yeah `n found: `n %class% = class `n  %title% = title  `n     %debug_ahk_class% = debug_ahk_class
}
```

BTW i produced video of the Problem and if you need some more information. please let me know! thanks!

Comment: good luck with finding someone with knowledge of "PhpStorm" AND AutoHotkey. Not having used the former, I have no idea what you are talking of

Comment: solved: When I was just at the closing of redundant window I have a 2x2 pixels small window found. Its not named "Debug" (as was determined in an earlier test). The window is now called "Run". A miracle that I have discovered that small windows (not useful in my opinion). I have his sized it with WinMove,,,,,600,300 and everything was usefull. The window name "Debug" originates possibly still on the version 8. I'm not quite sure, anyway, it was then also read with AutoHotkey. Whey it was sized to 2x2? :-D Whey it happes often?